# Two body problem equations for position and velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

In a simple two body problem, two point masses at rest at a certain distance that attract each other due to the force of gravity, starting from the differential equations of motion, how can you derive algebraic equations for position and velocity?

I know that there have been many similar questions and answers, I have checked them all out, and either they focus on other matters (for instance, time for the masses to meet), or they give some expressions e.g. for velocity that are different from answer to answer.

Any help would be appreciated. This is not a homework question, I am probably older than most of you, I am just a hobbyist with great gaps in my knowledge of calculus and I am trying to build a simulation of the two body problem.

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. Note that whether or not a problem was actually assigned as a homework problem is irrelevant on this site. Unfortunately, you are asking for a specific derivation, which actually is off-topic for this site. Perhaps you could focus your question in a little different way to make it better. What specific physics concept are you hung up on that is preventing you from performing this calculation yourself? Do you not understand something about Newton's law of gravitation, something about Newton's laws, forces, etc.?

Comment: I recognize that this is not an assigned homework problem, but I have put the "homework-and-exercises" tag, since this is still an exercise in how to use Newton's laws to formulate equations of motion.

Comment: Also do you know that a 2-body problem can be reduced to two 1-body problems?

Comment: Wikipedia has some info on this, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory#The_radial_Kepler_problem_(distance_as_function_of_time) & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_two-body_problem and the various articles those pages link to.

Comment: @AaronStevens - Is really questions on how to apply Newton's laws to construct a mathematical model of a systems off topic? Is applied math off-topic when it relates to the physical world or concepts? IMHO we're setting the bar too high then for the users, assuming they know all the tricks on how to apply the laws of physics in real life. I understand questions requiring a specific numeric answer being off-topic, but mathematical models shouldn't be.

Comment: @ja72 I never said questions about mathematical models should be off topic.

Comment: @AaronStevens - the way I read the question the _op_ is asking about a mathematical model, and I am quoting you here " Unfortunately, you are asking for a specific derivation, which actually is off-topic for this site".

Comment: @ja72 Yes. I don't think I said "questions about mathematical models are off topic"